# Suggested Edit queue renders tag-wiki-excerpts with Markdown Preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt, improve-edit

When you "Improve" a [tag-wiki-excerpt on the new Suggested Edit queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/682713), you get Markdown editing tools and a live Markdown-enabled-preview; which is wrong as Markdown isn't supported on tag-wiki-excerpts.

Sample for the Stack Overflow [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) tag - looks weird:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We started using the proper excerpt-editing UI when improving tag wiki excerpts:

> [image]

Comment: Note that the edit history for tag wiki excerpts is still Markdown enabled. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20087359/revisions